# How to update an array in MongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas, User, and Product. The User schema is where I store all the product ID and the number of items that the user added to the cart.

[image]

When the user makes a request to '/checkout' it should update the quantity and then remove it from the cart. I am having an issue when I checkout the quantity is not updating the quantity.

```
router.post('/checkout', auth, catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.session.userId);
    const err = [];
    if (user && user.products.length > 0) {

        user.products.map(async (product) => {
            let total = 0;
            const p = await Product.findById(product.productID);

            if (p.quantity > 0 && p.quantity > product.quantity) {
                console.log('IN');
                total = p.quantity - product.quantity;
                console.log(total);

                await Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: product.productID }, { $set: { quantity: total } });
            } else {
                err.push(`Item, ${p.name} is sold out`);
            }
        });
        await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.session.userId }, { $set: { products: [] } });
        if (err.length) {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'OK' });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Empty cart' });
}));
```

User Schema:

[image]

Product Schema:

[image: Product]

Comment: Could you please share the product collection schema.

Comment: @Jitendra I just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem in your code is at the `user.products.map(...)` function, because you never wait for all the promises you create in the map to resolve.

In other words, the `map` function returns an array of pending promises, but it will not wait for them to be done, and therefore the execution continues through the rest of the code reaching the `res.status(...)` before any of the code in `map` had been executed.

You have different options to solve it, but mainly you need to take care of the array of promises returned by the `map` function and wait for their completion, before you end your code. There is a very good explanation of how to handle this situation with `async/await` at [Google Developers Web fundamentals guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions#careful_avoid_going_too_sequential).

I usually leverage `Promise.all()` function, which returns a single promise from the array of promises, and therefore you can wait until the code in `map` is executed **in parallel** for each item in the array (i.e. `product` in your case). You can read more about it at [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

```js
// ...

let promisesArray = user.products.map(async product => {...});
// promisesArray should look like: [Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, … ]

// Using Promise.all we wait for each of them to be done in parallel
await Promise.all(promisesArray);

// Now you are certain the code in the map has been executed for each product

// ...
```

A good practice as well is to use `try {} catch(err) {}` block around the `Promise.all()` to handle cases of some promise being rejected.